# Best practice for replacing ng-include when upgrading from angularjs to angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-ng-include

To my dismay angular no longer supports the ng-include directive. My code base uses hundreds of shared partial html files. I cant seem to find any documentation. Can anyone point meet in the right direction. Is the best practice just to componentize every html file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngTemplateOutlet` directive as an alternative to `ng-include` in angular by passing a `TemplateRef`. Here I mentioned a sample code to do it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      child template which includes myTemplate
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"></ng-container>
    </div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() myTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p>Parent</p>
    <child [myTemplate]="myTemplate"></child>
    <ng-template #myTemplate>hi julia template!</ng-template>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('myTemplate', {read: TemplateRef}) myTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: was it helpful?@blankpage985

Comment: Maybe Im not explaining in the best way. I probably have 1000 html files that are used more than once. I currently display them using ng-include. I am wondering what the angular team would suggest I do to replace my ng-includes as they are no longer supported. It sounds like the answer is to create a component for each one (I used the word componentize). This is gonna take me a very long time so I just wanted to make sure this was the correct direction to go before I started. Didnt know if I may be missing something. @Sunny